# onclick create html object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make input type text refer to user input, if input 3 it shows 3 new input type text

I try this

```
<input type='text' id='how_many'><input type='button' id='add' value='add'>
<script>
       function add(){

          var total=$('#how_many).val();

          for(var x=0;x<=total;x++){
             //HOW TO ADD INPUT TYPE TEXT BELOW 
          }

       }
</script>
```

Comment: missing `'` change to `var total=$('#how_many').val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are missing '

```
var total=parseInt($('#how_many').val());


for(var x=0;x<=total;x++){
 $("#mainContainer").append("<input type='text'/>");
}
```

Comment: but i want if #add clicked twice it prevent loop / destroy loop

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type='text' id='how_many' />
</div>

<input type='button' id='add' value='add' />

<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#add").click(function(e) {
               var $el = $('#how_many'),
              total = $el.val();

              for (var x=0;x<=total;x++){
                  $(".container").append($el.val("").clone().attr("id", "total_" + x));
              }
          });
       });
</script>
```

Where '.clone()' is a jQuery method which clones the DOM node, '.append()' is a jQuery method to append the newly cloned node to another node.

Comment: And what triggers the add function?

Comment: how to add id in the clone of input type text based from loop for, like id='total_1',id='total_2'

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to more the onlick to the add button instead of the text input? Better yet, just use jQuery to bind it instead of the inline bind?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to parse your input, then just create:

```
var total= parseInt($('#how_many').val());

for(var x=0;x<=total;x++){
     $("yourcontainer").append("<input type='text' />");
}
```

Trigger the `add()` function on a `blur`

```
$("#how_many").blur(add);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    for (i=0;i<$('#how_many').val();i++) {
        $(this).after('<div><input type="text" /></div>')
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ws7gD/)**